# Optimal monetary policy under commitment & FOCs

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

[image]

[Clarida, Gali, Gertler(1999)](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/oekonomi/ECON4325/v14/pensumliste/cgg2000.pdf) show the optimal monetary policy problem of central bank for minimizing loss function under "Commitment"

[image] is a output gap, [image] is a inflation rate, [image]~AR(1) is a supply shock.

I want to know why rational expectations term, [image] , is omitted in the FOCs of the lagrangian above the Appendix.

For some variable [image], [image] does not imply [image].

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you read Gali's book http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10495.html, he says they use the law of iterated expectations to remove $E_t$ from the FOCS

Comment: My question is about omitted expectation operator "in the FOCs" not "in the lagrangian"